# Pass a list from a view to a form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.11

I have a view in my views.py and a form in my forms.py.
I need to pass my list[] of my view to my MultipleChoiceField of my form.

This is my code, I certainly miss something ...

Many Thanks

views.py

```
    def view_favorite(request):
        media = settings.MEDIA
        game_logo = settings.GAME_LOGO
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.method == 'POST' :
                return render(request, 'favorite.html', locals())
            else:
                favs = FavoriteGames.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values_list('game_id', flat=True)
                list = []
                for fav in favs:
                    game = Games.objects.get(id=fav)
                    list.append((game.id, game.guid, game.title, game.logo, "checked"), )
                    nogame = Games.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=favs)).values_list('id', 'guid', 'title', 'logo')
                form = GamesEditorForm(list)
```

forms.py

```
class GamesEditorForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, list, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GamesEditorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    favorite_games = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        initial=True,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        choices=list,
        )
```

Comment: If I understand your problem right, you want some initial data in your Form! To create a Form with initial data, in your view create your Form with form = YourForm(initial={"form_field": initial_data} )

Comment: I just try to pass my variable list[] to feed myMultipleChoiceField.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass you data directly as parameter in function

**views.py**

```
from .forms import my_func

def some_func(request):
    my_list = [1,2,3]
    my_func(request, my_list)
```

**forms.py**

```
def my_func(request, my_list):
    #Do something with my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is override the default init method for your form and handle all the logic when the form is created:

```
class YourOwnForm(forms.Form):
    a_field = forms.IntegerField(
        label="field",
        widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, your_custom_list=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Intantiation service.
        This method extends the default instantiation service.
        """
        super(CustomizationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      if your_custom_list:
            do stuff...
      else:
           error...
```

you would call it like this:

```
my_form = YourOwnForm(data, your_custom_list=[5,8,9])
```

Comment: Yes I tried your way, but I miss something I think, I put my code above, thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you need to make`self.list = list ` inside the` __init__` function. And do that assignation before calling`super()` since you need self to have self.list with data  before the initialization of each field in the form